# getting data from javascript to php and using it in getting data from mssql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

hi i have the following code which first pass the value from js file to php

```
function calldata(value) {
    alert(value);
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "data3.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: value,

    dataType: 'json',
    success: function()
    {
       alert("hi");
    }
});
    var z = "<table>";

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "data3.php",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            var p = 10;
            var j = 0;
            var m;
            z = z + "<tr><th></th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>lunch</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th></tr>";
            var k = response.length;
            if (k > 10)
                m = k / 10;
            for (var o = 0; o < m; o++) {
                z = z + "<tr>";

                for (j; j < p; j++) {
                    var obj = response[j];
                    var go = obj.subject;
                    z = z + "<td>" + go + "</td>";

                }
                z = z + "</tr>";

                p = p + 10;
            }
            z = z + "</table>";
            document.getElementById("jumbo").innerHTML = z;
        }



    });
```

in first i am trying to send  the value getting in calldata function to php via ajax and reciving it like 
`$variable = $_POST['value'];`

and trying to write a select query for getting data
`$sql = "SELECT * from class1 where class=$variable";`

but its not working can anyone please tell me right procedure or anything wrong with this code because i am not getting error

my php code is :

```php
$serverName = "esdapocnv01";
$connectionInfo = array( 'Database'=>'INDUS', 'UID'=>'testuser', 'PWD'=>'notmyrealpassword');

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";

}
$variable = $_POST['value'];

$sql = "SELECT * from class1 where class=$variable";

$emp1array=array();
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    //example of adding extra data if required
    $emp1array[]=$row;

}

echo json_encode($emp1array);


sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Comment: What did you try in debugging your code?

Comment: yes i tried there is no error

Comment: i used chrome debugger its showing no error

Comment: Debugging includes inspecting values, flow of control. For instance, did you check what the value of your `$_GET['value']` is?

Comment: actually while debugging its not entering the ajax call only

Comment: You have two ajax calls, why?

Comment: actually first one to post the required value in php so that i can use that value to filter data then second ajax is for getting data from that php after filtering

Comment: That is an error in logic. You should make one ajax call only: PHP treats the request and sends a response on *that* request. Now you are calling PHP twice, but the second time without any information passed, so it cannot give a good answer, yet that is the answer you are walking away with. Join the two ajax requests

Comment: Please include your PHP code as well, I suspect there might be issues there as well.

Comment: done please have a look

Comment: can you tell an alternate way to perform the required function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a response from the server you should not issue two Ajax calls. The idea is that you make one request via Ajax, and get the response to that in the *success* handler.

So, join the two Ajax calls, like this:

```
function calldata(value) {
    alert(value);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "data3.php",
        type: 'post',
        //async: false, // why? Don't block your browser! Leave this out.
        data: {value: value}, // key/value, so PHP finds your data as "value"
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            var p = 10;
            var j = 0;
            var m; 
            var z = "<table>"; // moved here
            z = z + "<tr><th></th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>lunch</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th></tr>";
            // Note: z needs one more column (10 in total!)
            var k = response.length;
            // if (k > 10) // remove this IF, you need a value in ALL cases.
                m = k / 10;
            for (var o = 0; o < m; o++) {
                z = z + "<tr>";
                for (j; j < p; j++) {
                    var obj = response[j];
                    var go = obj.subject;
                    z = z + "<td>" + go + "</td>";
                }
                z = z + "</tr>";
                p = p + 10;
            }
            z = z + "</table>";
            document.getElementById("jumbo").innerHTML = z;
        }
    });
    // Note that any code that follows here will be executed 
    // before the above success handler will be called.
}
```

Also check some other suggested changes in the above code (commented).

In PHP, I suggest also some modifications (commented in code), most importantly, your current code is vulnerable for SQL injection, and you should make sure all your output is JSON encoded (even error messages):

```
// indicate that you're going to return JSON:
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$serverName = "esdapocnv01";
$connectionInfo = array( 'Database'=>'INDUS', 'UID'=>'testuser', 'PWD'=>'notmyrealpassword');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    // json_encode your errors:
    die( json_encode(sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
    // removed echo, because code after die is never executed
}
// check if value is posted:
if (!isset($_POST['value'])) {
    // json_encode error message:
    die(json_encode(["error" => "value is missing"]));
}

$variable = $_POST['value'];

// prevent SQL injection, use parameters (?)
$sql = "SELECT * from class1 where class=?";

$emp1array=array();
// pass variable in a parameter array:
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, array($variable)); 
if( $stmt === false) {
    // json encode the error list:
    die( json_encode( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    //example of adding extra data if required
    $emp1array[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($emp1array);

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Comment: its not working while debugging in chrome again its not entering the ajax call

Comment: What does that mean "not entering"?

Comment: i am adding breakpoints to line and watching how program is running step by step as soon as its alerting value its going direcly to  z = z + "</table>"; this line

Comment: So that proves that the Ajax request and response **are** happening. What is `alert(response)` showing?

Comment: response
[Object0: "42000"1: 1022: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'A'."SQLSTATE: "42000"code: 102message: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'A'."__proto__: Object]

Comment: i should get subject name here

Comment: but i my select query is right it was working before also

Comment: I had to make a fix:  `array(1, $variable)` should be just `array($variable)`

Comment: thanks a lot dude its working ..thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` variable is a `JSON object`? If it isn't you have to send your variable like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "data3.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: { key_name: value },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function()
    {
       alert("hi");
    }
});
```

On 'key_name' you can write the name that you want to use in `php`. Then in your `php`code you can access to the value using `$_POST["key_value"]`.

**EDIT:**

I wrote the next code to test it:

index.php

```
<body>
    <input type="button" class="send" value="send" />
    <script>

        $(".send").on("click", function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "post",
                data: "world",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

        })

    </script>
</body>
```

test.php

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
```

On the first execution the value sent to the server is a `string` `data: "world"` and the result is:

```
array (size=1)
  empty
array (size=0)
  empty
```

On the second execution the value sent to the server is a `json object` `data: { value: "world" }`

And that's what I got from the server:

```
array (size=1)
  'value' => string 'world' (length=5)
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: no its not a json object and can you please tell me that will using two ajax call in same function will create a problem??

Comment: I wrote a sample to test the code and I get a response if I use a `json object`

Comment: can you please  have a look at my php code if something wrong there??